# My Tomcat is not running it just open and close when I click on tomcat7.exe

Tags: java, tomcat

I am installing Tomcat 7 in my PC it works in Eclipse but when I try to open in `bin/` tomcat7.exe  it just open and closes, (I am stopping the server in Eclipse). Also, in Eclipse I'am trying to open admin console like `URL:(localhost:1234/admin)` it shows 404 error. Can anyone who knows this problem explain a solution?

Comment: you might not have added configured properly catalina.bat file.Edit the catailina.bat file and give the jdk 
 path

Comment: in catalina.bat file what am i edit i change my jdk path previously jdk 1.6 now am changed to 1.7

Comment: was it working in jdk1.6 and after you changed it to jdk1.7,it does not work?

Comment: no i change path variable in system varible 1.6 to 1.7 it works in eclipse not in manually..

Comment: try out catalina.bat command in ur tomcat/bin folder,
or try out catalina.bat run command there it will open tomcat in the same cmd window and will also show the exception which are causing the error

Answer (score 16):

If you are using Windows, you can follow the following to run `tomcat7.exe` :

1. Open your Command prompt (`cmd`)
2. Set your `JAVA_HOME` or `JRE_HOME`. Eg. `set JRE_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jre7`
3. Go to the directory of your tomcat. Eg. `cd  C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.35\bin`
4. Run `startup.bat` file. Eg. `startup`.

This should start your tomcat server without using Eclipse.

Comment: yes i tried this one also but i got error  
The JRE_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program

Comment: yes now working fine, for every time i have to follow  this steps? any alternative is there.   thanks..

Comment: You can set your JAVA_HOME/JRE_HOME in the system/user variables so that you dont have to set it each time you need to run tomcat. For doing this, go to My computer and right click to get System properties , then go to  Advanced tab and click on Environment Variables. In System variables, click on New and add variable Name JRE_HOME and variable value C:\Program Files\Java\jre7  and click ok. Now you can just run startup.bat by double clicking on it to start up tomcat server.

Answer (score 12):

First Set **JAVA_HOME** and **CLASSPath** path

For Windows Java Path Settings

1. Right click on **Computer** and open **Properties**.
2. In Windows Vista or Windows 7, go to **Advanced System Settings**.
       Else go to next step. Go to **Advanced Tab** and click on **Environment
       Variables** button.

[image]

3. Select **CLASSPath** under the list of **System Variables**, and press Edit and add  If CLASSPath not available there click New button add 
   **C:\Program Files\java\jre 1.x.x_xx\bin**
       after a semicolon.

[image]

1. Now click on New' button under system variables and enter
       JAVA_HOME as variable name and path to jdk home directory (ex.
       **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.x.x_xx**

[image]

After Completing **Java Path Settings**

---

- Go to the directory of your Tomcat. Eg. cd C:\Program
  Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.35\bin
- Run startup.bat file
  [image]

Answer (score 10):

To start your application server in Windows :

1. Open command prompt .(Run as Administrator).
2. Go to the path (`..\apache-tomcat-8.0.27\bin`) and run `startup.bat`
3. A new command prompt opens up and should stay unclosed to tell your server is in running state.

If command prompt opens and closes automatically, then the reason can be as below.

1. tomcat is already in started state in Eclipse.
2. Check the connector port configured in `server.xml` file and check if that port is free in your local machine. [`netstat` command]
3. Change the connector port to some unused port, preferably in `80XX` series.

Let me know if you are able to invoke `localhost:(the http connector port)` you have configured in `server.xml` through you web browser.

Comment: 4. it could also be a user permission problem, ensure your user has write permissions on the <TOMCAT_HOME>/webapps directory and add user write permission if he doesn't have

Answer (score 2):

You don't start Tomcat by double clicking the exe, use the batch files instead.
startup.bat starts the server, shutdown.bat stops it again.
And ignore the advise to get the service installer. You don't need those unless you want the server to start on system boot and run in the background. Which you don't want unless you're going to configure a production server, which you aren't here.
The batch files are in the same directory on your computer as the exe.

Answer (score 2):

you have to set JAVA_HOME and  JRE_HOME in System environment.while setting the JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME, you should assure that JRE path that you are setting is corresponding to the JDK whose path you have set in JAVA_HOME. some time what happens that there may be more than one JDK in the system so conflict occurs. better to have only one JDK and corresponding JRE.

Answer (score 2):

**This is probably due to a bad setup of an environment variable.**

For example, if you setup incorrect `JAVA_OPTS`, tomcat startup will fail.

You can check your configuration by calling : `catalina configtest`

Here an example of the output for bad setup of `JAVA_OPTS` :

> Error occurred during initialization of VM Could not reserve enough space for object heap
>
> Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
>
> Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

Comment: `catalina configtest` saved my life. My `JRE_HOME` points to a 1.6 version jre which give me error `Unsupported major.minor version 51.0`.

Answer (score 2):

It works for me after updating the jdk path in JAVA_HOME compatible to your tomcat version in user Variables.[image]

Answer (score 1):

the JAVA_HOME and JRE_HOME environment variables set should not have semicolon or ; at the end...I was facing similar problem...removed semi-colon or ; from the end and tomcat server started from cmd screen after running startup command(of tomcat..bin folder).

Answer (score 1):

I checked environment variables and compiler version everything was fine, deleting junk files from work folder worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Check your **JRE_HOME** location in environment variables. if it didn't work then try

1). Open **CMD** in administration mode.
2). locate to your tomcat directory.
3). run **startup.bat** --->> It will show your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the tomcat 32-bit/64-bit Windows Service Installer (pgp, md5) as in this set up is given which will install tomcat on your PC and you can also start and stop tomcat using the tomcat service.

Comment: wrong. That's not what you want for a development machine.

Comment: http://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi i downloded this site 64bit pgp/md5 under core title

Answer (score 0):

In my experience tomcat7 might not like it if JAVA_PATH or JDK_PATH contain bracket symbols like in "Program Files (x86)". Make sure you format path in your environmental variables correctly or move your JDK to another folder.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had some reference to a jar file in catilana.bat, but the jar I had removed from my system. Tomcat started successfully once I removed that reference from catilana.bat

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with Apache Tomcat 9 version.

Solution is very simple.

Apache Tomcat 9 is supported by Java 8 and later versions. So, I had **JRE_HOME** with JRE7 path, I binded it to new **JRE8** and everything works fine.

Different versions of Apache Tomcat are available for different versions of the Servlet and JSP specifications. The mapping between the specifications and the respective Apache Tomcat versions is:

[image]